# PHPmailer SMTP auth configuration

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, smtp-auth

Something doesn't work with my phpmailer smtp.
The php page should connect to an smtp authenticated server (with username and password), then authenticate to the specific mailbox I choose with username and password.

Basically I have a two-step authentication: one to the server, one to the mailbox.

- What the username and password below refer to?
- How could I login to the server (with user and password) and then to
  the mailbox (other user and other password)?

Thank you to who will be able to help me.

```
// SMTP auth
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth     = ($smtp['auth'] ? true : false);
$mail->SMTPSecure   = ($smtp['secure'] ? $smtp['secure'] : false);
$mail->Host         = $smtp['host'];
$mail->Port         = $smtp['port'];
$mail->Username     = $smtp['username'];
$mail->Password     = $smtp['password'];
```

Answer (score 1):

To send email using SMTP authentication, you only need to log in once with a username and password permitted to relay through that server. When an SMTP server is also the Mail Exchanger (MX) for a domain, the username and password used for SMTP authentication are usually the same as those used to receive email using POP3/IMAP, where the mailbox exists on a Mail Delivery Agent ([MDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent)) .

SMTP has no concept of mailboxes, it is only concerned with accepting messages from Mail User Agents (MUA), receiving messages from Message Transfer Agents (MTA) or submitting emails to a Mail Submission Agent ([MSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_submission_agent)), all of which communicate using the [SMTP protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt).

Comment: "_the username and password used for SMTP authentication are usually the same_"... and when they are not?

Comment: Then you need specific credentials that allow you to relay, but there is still only one username/password combination to use. There is no secondary login after authenticating.

Comment: I asked my provider and answered that auth smtp is at a domain level, not at mailbox level. So, I have:

- username: auth@domain.com
- password: xxx

but I need to send email from info@domain.com. How can I do that with phpmailer? I can't specify two different usernames.

Comment: I know this must have been resolved more than a year ago but... you don't have to specify two different user names. The domain level username (and password) allows access to the SMTP server. The e-mail can be "from" **anyone** by using the $mail->setFrom() method (no password required).